# Stick to JavaScript Date standard format?

Tags: javascript, date

*After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript) - which also provides links to documentation , I still have a question about the documentation.*

MDN : `Date.parse`

> A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date.

Ok  , [RFC2282](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) :

```
date-time       =       [ day-of-week "," ] date FWS time [CFWS]
day-of-week     =       ([FWS] day-name) / obs-day-of-week
day-name        =       "Mon" / "Tue" / "Wed" / "Thu" /
                       "Fri" / "Sat" / "Sun"

date            =       day month year
year            =       4*DIGIT / obs-year
month           =       (FWS month-name FWS) / obs-month
month-name      =       "Jan" / "Feb" / "Mar" / "Apr" /
                        "May" / "Jun" / "Jul" / "Aug" /
                        "Sep" / "Oct" / "Nov" / "Dec"

day             =       ([FWS] 1*2DIGIT) / obs-day
```

Now - [ISO8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)

```
 Year:
      YYYY (eg 1997)
   Year and month:
      YYYY-MM (eg 1997-07)
   Complete date:
      YYYY-MM-DD (eg 1997-07-16)
```

Ok.

Questions :

- MDN provided a pattern sample (which is working) `"Dec 25, 1995"` which is **not** found in 2282 nor in ISO .
  How come this sample works ? the order must be `day month year`  ( according to 2282) .
- the separators in the standards are `[space]` ( in 2282) and `[-]` in ISO.

  So why this sample works ( cross browser) ? `Date.parse("2011/11/23")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Date.parse`, have a look at the [EcmaScript specification, section 15.9.4.2](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.4.2):

> The String may be interpreted as a local time, a UTC time, or a time
>   in some other time zone, depending on the contents of the String. The
>   function *first attempts to parse* the format of the String according to
>   the rules called out in [Date Time String Format (15.9.1.15)](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15). If the
>   String does not conform to that format the function may *fall back to
>   any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date
>   formats*. Unrecognizable Strings or dates containing illegal element
>   values in the format String shall cause `Date.parse` to return `NaN`.

So, MDN's Mozilla-specific documentation is quite near that. The official "EcmaScript Date Time String Format" is a subset of ISO 8601, otherwise Gecko browsers try to interpret it as RFC 2822 or even something else (this might include `"Dec 25, 1995"`). I strongly suspect that `"2011/11/23"` really works cross-browser, although it might be true for recent versions.

Comment: too abstract : "any implementation-specific heuristics ...". what are the other formats? where can i see them ?

Comment: Yes, it is too abstract. Every browser implements its own formats, and old IEs do not even parse the EcmaScript Format correctly.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I'm getting `1353625200000`, obviously due to different timezone settings.

Comment: what time zone problems ? it is a valid date. and the separators are ok.. (ISO).

Comment: Not really problems, just different timezone settings (edited comment). Sure, it parses correctly, but does not return the UTC date

Comment: im FF its ok. the prob is with IE

Comment: On Internet Explorer: It does provide a spec-compliant parse (for ISO dates) only since version 9 (non-quirks), see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20808/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-bergi)